# Google Bar Charts width

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How can I show all the **years** in a straight line instead of the way they are now. First image is what I want, second image is what I have.

[image: This is what I want]

[image: This is what I want]

```
var options = {
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 500,
    "hAxis":{showTextEvery:1},
    'legend': { position: 'top' },

};
```

Comment: Can you post code snippet of your code? it would be faster to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = {
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 500,
    "hAxis":{showTextEvery:1, maxAlternation:1, minTextSpacing:1},
    'legend': { position: 'top'},

};
```

I have figured it out.